# Reduce android app bundle size (.aab). How to not export some image resource file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-bundle

There are many image resource files in my app under s folder.
I would like to keep it but when export .aab I would like to exclude these img res file.
Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To remove unused resources, you can use the option `shrinkResources` in your build.gradle file. How to do so is explained in more details in [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code).

Then, shipping resources of different densities to different devices is handled automatically by the App Bundle when Play generates the APKs. Keep in mind that what matters is not the size of the AAB as much as the size of the APKs that will be sent to your users.