# How to shrink the size of AAR file produced by building an Android Library Module?

Tags: android, android-library, aar

I have seen the Android Developer Documentation on shrinking APK size. But, for a library module, I couldn't find a proper documentation or tutorial for shrinking the AAR file size. So, how to achieve smaller AAR file size ?

Comment: refer --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61321596/reduce-android-app-bundle-size-aab-how-to-not-export-some-image-resource-fil

Comment: I guess you inferred **AAR** as **AAB**. My doubt is regarding **AAR** (Android Archive) produced by building Library Module.